# Is there any logical reason to "store" just one object file (.o) into archival file (.a)?

Tags: compiler, go, compilation

As far as I understand (not much), the archival `.a` file is just, roughly speaking, the collection/batch of object `.o` files. It's like a library of compiled code that can be cached and which can be used later by the linker when creating the exe file. **So my question is there any logic for the .a file to consist of only one .o file.**

I am asking because Golang language use package (collection of `.go` files) as a translation/compilation unit (not a single `.g`o file), and since the compiler, as I understand, for every compilation unit creates `.o` file, it means that in this case it will for package of, for example, 5 files create only one `.o` file. So I am wondering what is the point of storing just one .o file inside `.a` file, and not keeping just `.o` file. It would have logic to me if the compiler creates `.o` file for every `.go` file inside package and then "group" them into `.a` file, but this way not.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the traditional linker will extract only necessary object files from the `.a`s, but if you provide a `.o` on the command line that traditional linker will include that whole `.o` regardless of whether its symbols are referenced from others.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thanks for the replay. I am not sure if I understood you, but that sounds the same? Extracting the necessary object file from `.a` or just passing `.o` files on the command line (I mean, we won't pass `.o` files that we do not need)?

Comment: Right, no reason to pass `.o` files you don't need on command line!  The feature of `.a` is that all `.o` therein are optional, whether there's just one or many, and, each `.o` therein is only pulled into the final executable by the need for resolution of unresolved symbols,  So, yeah, if you have only one `.o` and know for sure it is needed, then putting that `.o` into `.a` seems like overkill (but harmless).  (There may be some library search path advantages for `.a`, don't recall.)

Comment: @ErikEidt I was searching a little bit. Well, yes, the entire package (that is, all `.go` files) would be compiled into single `.o` file and in most cases it would be the only content of `.a` file, but in some cases the `.a` file can also additionally include `.o` files for different assembly and C files (if any of them is used).

Comment: IMO, archiving a single object file into an archive file can be beneficial in scenarios where you want to maintain a consistent structure or naming convention across your project. It can also simplify build process by treating single object file as part of a larger collection, even if that collection currently consists of only one file. Also it can help in organizing and managing project dependencies more efficiently.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub Nice!

Comment: Want me post it as an answer?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub That would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archiving a single object file into an archive file can be beneficial in scenarios where you want to maintain a consistent structure or naming convention across your project. It can also simplify build process by treating single object file as part of a larger collection, even if that collection currently consists of only one file. Also it can help in organizing and managing project dependencies more efficiently.